# Invalid property 'id' of bean class FlatFileItemReader, file read and Entity used has id

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-batch

I'm currently working on a batch program that reads csv files, then inserts the data using hibernate and I believe JPA.

The error that I'm running into is the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader]: Could not find field for property during fallback access!
```

I've tried the following to resolve the issue:

- The error was coming up when reading a file that didn't have a column named id. Tried only files that had an id filed. Same issue remained
- Found on here that the issue might be missing an id field (found on an SO thread), so added getter and setters wit the following for id fields in the Entity class.

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

and for files that didn't have an id

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE) 
private Long id;
```

but the same issue occurred.

The getters and setters are structured as such.

```
public Long getId() { return id; }

public void setId(final Long id) { this.id = id; }
```

- Another thread here suggested using Long instead of int (what they were originally) was the cause. Turns out it was.
- The code that the issue was occurring at in the debugger referred to this code, namely the save method

  public interface LCBOInventoryRepository extends CrudRepository {

  ```
  @Override
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public LCBOInventory save(LCBOInventory lcboInventoryObject);
  ```

but every object that is being passed into that method should have the Id information available as mention earlier.

As requested, here is the code for the reader and writer being used for the process that this issue is occuring on.

Reader:

```
@Component
public class LCBOInventoryReader extends AbstractLCBOReader implements ItemReader, InterstepDataRetriever {

    @Autowired
    public LCBOInventoryReader(final String currentCSVFilePathKey ) {
        this.currentCSVFilePathKey = currentCSVFilePathKey;
    }

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LCBOInventoryReader.class);

    @Override
    public ItemReader<LCBOInventory> read() throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        Class<LCBOInventory> classType = LCBOInventory.class;

        return createCSVReader(classType, currentCSVFilePath, inventoryTrackerProperties.getLCBOFilPropertiess().getInventory());
    }

    @Override
    public void retrieveInterstepDataFromJobContext(final ExecutionContext jobContext) {
        this.currentCSVFilePath = (String) jobContext.get(currentCSVFilePathKey);
    }
}
```

And here is the Abstract class that is extended:

```
public abstract class AbstractLCBOReader {

    @Autowired
    protected LCBOInventoryTrackerProperties inventoryTrackerProperties;

    protected String currentCSVFilePathKey;
    protected String currentCSVFilePath;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractLCBOReader.class);

    protected <T> ItemReader<T> createCSVReader(final Class<T> classType,
                                                 final String currentCSVFilePath,
                                                 final LCBOFileDetailsProperties properties) {

        FlatFileItemReader<T> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        // Skip a line to ignore the header information in these files
        reader.setLinesToSkip(properties.getNumberOfLinesToSkipInFile());
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(currentCSVFilePath + File.separator + properties.getFileName()));
        reader.setLineMapper(createLineMapper(classType, properties));
        reader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy());
        reader.setEncoding("utf8");

        return reader;
    }

    private <T> LineMapper<T> createLineMapper(final Class<T> classType, final LCBOFileProperties.LCBOFileDetailsProperties properties) {
        DefaultLineMapper<T> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(createLineTokenizer(properties));
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(createFieldSetMapper(classType));

        return lineMapper;
    }

    private <T> FieldSetMapper<T> createFieldSetMapper(final Class<T> classType) {
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<T> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(classType);

        return fieldSetMapper;
    }

    private LineTokenizer createLineTokenizer(final LCBOFileProperties.LCBOFileDetailsProperties properties) {
        LCBOFileProperties.Column[] columns = properties.getColumns();
        int[] columnIndexes = new int[columns.length];
        String[] columnNames = new String[columns.length];

        // populating the columnIndexes
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            columnIndexes[i] = columns[i].getColumnIndex();
            columnNames[i] = columns[i].getColumnName();
        }

        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setIncludedFields(columnIndexes);
        lineTokenizer.setNames(columnNames);
        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        lineTokenizer.setQuoteCharacter('"');

        return lineTokenizer;
    }
}
```

And the interface InterstepDataRetriever that the reader implements

```
public interface InterstepDataRetriever {

    @BeforeStep
    default void retrieveValuesFromStepContext(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
        ExecutionContext jobContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
        retrieveInterstepDataFromJobContext(jobContext);
    }

    void retrieveInterstepDataFromJobContext(ExecutionContext jobContext);
}
```

The latter shouldn't have any effect on this issue, but was included for completeness (besides you never know).

<del>Writer(Old):</del>

```
@Component
public class LCBOInventoryWriter implements ItemWriter<LCBOInventory> {

    @Autowired
    private LCBOInventoryRepository inventoryDAO;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends LCBOInventory> lcboInventoryItem) throws Exception {
        inventoryDAO.save(lcboInventoryItem);
    }
}
```

Writer(New - this was put in the same file as the Step ):

```
@Bean
public ItemWriter<LCBOStore> writer() {
    HibernateItemWriter writer = new HibernateItemWriter();
    writer.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    System.out.println("writing stuff");
    return writer;
}
```

Here's the stack trace when executing the code (edit: stacktrace has been updated):

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:783) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1520) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:648) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:640) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:635) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemWriter.doWrite(HibernateItemWriter.java:140) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemWriter.write(HibernateItemWriter.java:113) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:392) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:214) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:231) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:123) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:117) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:776) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at com.lcbo.config.LCBOBatchConfig.main(LCBOBatchConfig.java:173) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
```

So in a nutshell I'm at a loss as to what id field it needs to work, why it thinks that it's an entity (there's no @Entity annotation), and how i can either satisfy what it needs, or fix it so that it's not required.

Comment: To the person that said this should be closed, could a posting of why be made so the question can be improved?

Comment: Can you share the configuration for your reader and writer?

Comment: @MichaelMinella of course. I've updated the question with those files added.

Comment: Can you provide more of the stack trace?

Comment: @MichaelMinella sure thing. Please see the latest edit

Comment: Do you have accessors for the id field?

Comment: @MichaelMinella within the Entity classes? If so then yes there are getters and setters for the id field. I'll include those above as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're passing in the correct `Class<T> classType` to the `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper`?

This error makes it appear as if you're passing in the `FlatFileItemReader` class rather than `LCBOInventory`.

> NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.batch.item.file.**FlatFileItemReader**]:

---

**UPDATE:** Please check the `write` method of your writer. The stack trace shows the error is coming from there, not from your reader. Is it possible you're trying to persist a `FlatFileItemReader` object?

> LCBOInventoryWriter.write(LCBOInventoryWriter.java:19)

Comment: Just set a breakpoint on         BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<T> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>(); and executed. The classType variable was for LCBOInventory.

Comment: The updated full stack trace show's it's failing at `LCBOInventoryWriter.write(LCBOInventoryWriter.java:19`, not in the reader

Comment: Can you add an exception breakpoint for `NotReadablePropertyException` and inspect the objects where the exception is thrown? I don't know why/how, but it looks like the JPA repository is trying to persist a `FlatFileItemWriter`.

Comment: I've included the stack trace as requested, and I think you might be on to something. I wouldn't be surprised if it's misconfigured, it's the first project utilising hibernate/JPA

Comment: My guess is that Spring Data got confused into thinking that the `FlatFileItemReader` is an entity. Hibernate alone surely wouldn't do that since it's not annotated as such, but I'm less familiar with the inner-workings Spring Data. I personally would try ditching Spring Data. Instead, I would just use Hibernate and the out-of-the-box `HibernateItemWriter` rather than your custom one.

Comment: Well I've scrapped spring data and jpa, having all writers going to a Bean that I've linked above. And it now provides a new error stating there's no entity for FlatFileItemReader, which is.....confusing.

Comment: Somehow, somewhere, there's a reference to a `FlatFileItemReader`. Is it possible that the `LCBOInventory` object has a reference to the `FlatFileItemReader`? I feel like I'm just guessing blindly without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this. TO answer your question, LCBOInventory is a object structure class that has no reference to FlatFileItemReader, but I beleive where it's happening is when a custom reader is created, the read() method returns a FlatFileItemReader refference. Which doesn't happen when the FlatFileItemReader code is in the reader's constructor.

But this is starting to become a new issue, so might have to flag this as something in the Hibernate configuration that was wrong. Just not sure what exactly it was.

Comment: Yea, I'd definitely dig deeper into why the reader's `read()` method is returning a reference to a `FlatFileItemReader` instance. Solve that and you should be good to go.

Comment: I believe i found the issue. In a nutshell the reader was missing some components that didn't actually read the file but just sent back the created FlatFIleItemReader object

Comment: That would absolutely lead to some issues :-P